# Crypto++ Multiplicative inverses do not reciprocate in ModularArithmetic group

Tags: discrete-logarithm

My mathematical assumption is $(g^rx')^x = g^r$ where $x'$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x$ and $g$ is the generator of the group. I am calculating $(g^rx')^x$ in `ModularArithmetic` group `G` using Crypto++.

```
CryptoPP::Integer a, b, c, r(rng, 1, p);
a = G.Exponentiate(g, r);
b = G.Exponentiate(G.Exponentiate(g, G.MultiplicativeInverse(x)), r);
c = G.Exponentiate(b, x);
std::cout << "c = " << a  << std::endl;
std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
```

I am expecting `a == c` But I see `a` and `c` are completely different.

```
a = 1930186808310718502797115181829348128116...
b = 2074612869164222925611442905270407839427...
c = 6800929086281603423987465129823606881371...
```

I tried $ (g^{x'})^{x} $ expecting that to be $g$, but that also is different from $g$. But $xx' = 1$

```
G.Multiply(x, G.MultiplicativeInverse(x)) // But this is 1
G.Exponentiate(G.Exponentiate(g, G.MultiplicativeInverse(x)), x) // NOT g
```

I am generating Private key using `CryptoPP::DSA::PrivateKey` and using the `PrivateExponent` as `x`.

```
CryptoPP::DSA::PrivateKey sk;
sk.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, key_size);
CryptoPP::DSA::PublicKey pk;
pk.AssignFrom(sk);
CryptoPP::Integer g, p, q, x, gx;
pk.GetValue("SubgroupGenerator", g);
pk.GetValue("SubgroupOrder", q);
pk.GetValue("Modulus", p);
pk.GetValue("PublicElement", gx);
sk.GetValue("PrivateExponent", x);
```

Then I am creating a group

```
CryptoPP::ModularArithmetic G(p);
```

Is my mathematical assumption wrong ? or there is a problem in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried $(g^{x′})^x$ expecting that to be $g$, but that also is different from $g$. But $xx′=1$

Here's the issue; we have $(g^a)^b = 1$ when $a \cdot b \equiv 1 \bmod {p-1}$.  Note the $p-1$ part, that's important.

You're setting $b=x$ and finding $a = x' = x^{-1} \bmod p$; that'd different.  If you tried $x' = x^{-1} \bmod p-1$, then it would work.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. But does it work **sometimes**.  Sometimes I do not get one as the output. When I get $xx^{-1 (mod p-1)}$ is `0` not `1`. Both `H.Multiply(x, H.MultiplicativeInverse(x))` and `G.Multiply(x, H.MultiplicativeInverse(x))` yields `0`. Sometimes `b=1` probably the problem is in `r`. For some $r$ I get $(g^{x^{-1}})^{r} = 1$, but I have checked $r \neq r$. How do I choose a good $r$ that does not make $b=0$ ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: I suspect you have `H.MultiplicativeInverse(x)` = 0.  I don't know how you've defined `H`, however since `G` is a field, the only way the result of a multiply is 0 is if one of the two inputs is 0.

Comment: Yes $x^{-1} = 0$. But $x$ is the private key. Why would it's inverse be $0$ ? Is that something like a **standard practice** to generate such values as private key ? How can I avoid this type of key ? I see generating an checking the inverse as the only option. Or if I depend on the inverse of the private key in my formulation am I doing something very wrong which is against that standard practice ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: is $H$ even?  If so, then if $x$ is also even, then $x^{-1}$ won't exist (and your library might return 0 as an error indication).  In that case, $g^{x y } \ne g$ in general, that is, no such $y$ will exist for at least half the possible $x$ values.  We typically work in a prime-sized subgroup (and set $H$ to that prime) to avoid such issues.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, H is the group of $p-1$ so yes H is always even because $p$ is prime. At least I assume so as I am generating DSA private key.

Comment: @NeelBasu: DSA?  Someone's still using that?  Well, in any case, select H to be the prime size of the subgroup (generally denoted $q$) that $G$ generates, and all should be good...

Comment: But as you have mentioned in your answer that the multiplicative inverse has to be taken in $mod\, (p-1)$ if I want $g^{xx^{-1}} = g\; (mod p)$.If $p$ is prime then $p-1$ has to be an even number. So I made `H` to be a ring over `p-1`. Can I choose a different ring while still having $g^{xx^{-1}} = g\; (mod p)$ ?